# Why jumbo frames affects the performance of the server

Tags: performance

Update: Should I only set jumbo frame to server and file server, not client?

If so, is there any impact on communication between server and client?

---

I am running some performance test for our product.

Currently all the testing related machines(servers, file servers, clients, db) are on a 10G network connected by a powerful Dell OpenManage Switch.

We are using iscsi for the file server. We have a cluster server that contains several nodes.

The performance test I am running basically is to simulate the following scenario:
1. client machine will create a large number of threads to send http request to the server.
2. Based on the different type of requests, server needs to get some data from file server which is shared by all the other server nodes.

The test results is:
Without jumbo frames, MTU 1500, server CPU 70%, and avg response time for the http request is 1 second.

With jumbo frames, MTU 9000, server CPU 20%, and avg response time for the http request is 5 seconds.

We have configured jumbo frames on all machines, and changed TCP settings.

Any ideas?

Comment: Jumbo frames should only be used for hosts accessing the iSCSI storage device, not from a client to the server fronting said storage.

Comment: But if I set client to 1500, and server to 9000, then server will still send 9000 to the client. Will that be a problem?

Comment: Only turn on jumbo frames for the iSCSI interfaces. You have dedicated interfaces for that, correct?

Comment: @Doug Did you mean: file server machines enable jumbo frames, all the other machines use standard MTU?

Answer (score 3):

Well:

- Bigger frames = more data on each package = your CPU works less to send data (it has a smaller number of packages per second), but takes longer to assemble each payload (more latency).
- Smaller frames = less data on each package = your cpu works more to send data (more packages per second), but takes less time to assemble each payload (less latency).

Comment: Add to that apossible windows firewall.... can have significant impact on CPU usage... per packet.

Comment: And you need to add CPU load on the switches as well. Also less interupts need to be serviced for a the volume of data - I guess that really comes down to less CPU required to do the work though, depending on how you look at it.

Comment: I expect the CPU to be lower, but I don't think response time of http request should be 5 times longer

Comment: Just imagine that a lot of data must be put together to assemble a Jumbo package before it leaving the interface.

Comment: But if you think one level upper, for application level, they still need to get a complete http request. Maybe one request can be encapsulated into one 9000 frame, and into several 1500 frams, but the total time should be the same from sending a request to receiving the request.

Comment: No. It will still try to fill the frame before sending it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. From app perspective, it doesn't matter which MTU we use, the time from sending the same http request and receiving the request should be the same, is it?

Comment: From the app yes, but you still constrained to the lower layers.

Comment: If from app is yes, then the response time of http request should be the same, is it?

Comment: Only if it doesn't pass by the physical layer. If it pass by the physical layer, it will have the cost involved with Jumbo frames. They are *stacked layers*  that means that the app layer is encapsulated on the lower layers and all its overheads. See [this](http://www.tutorial5.com/images/stories/osi-model-7-layers.png) image.

Comment: I know the stack. But my point is: less packets + more latency == more packets + less latency

Comment: Yes.. but more latency = more latency on everything.

Comment: But it is on IP stack. On app stack it should be considered together.

Comment: @Tomtom these are Ethernet frames not IP packets. A firewall typically does not monitor layer 2.

Comment: But the CPU needs. You load 10k data. Standard ethernet packets = 1500 bytes. Jumbo = varies - can be a lot more (I know switches handling 64k frames). a 9000 byte jumbo frame is a LOT less packets for the firewall to handle. A lot less IP (!) packets, as the size of the IP packets varies, not only the size of the Ethernet packets.

Comment: The computer will put together IP packets as large as it can - to fit into the size that it gets up from the lower levels. So, 1 ethernet frame = 1 ip packet, regardless of the payload. That is a lot less packets to inspect for the firewall.

Comment: These are all Linux machines

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to read up and understand more about the impact of utilising Jumbo frames, and *why* it still hasn't become mainstream after more than a decade. This paper hints on the real world problems faced by Jumbo frame sizes, preventing it from achieving more than the bulk-file-transfer scenario.

http://www.chelsio.com/jumbo_enet_frames.html

Summary of issues contributing to high-latency delays

1. Delayed pipelining across transmission mediums
2. Small transmit/receive buffers causing dropped packets = retransmit
3. Larger packet size = higher chance of collision = retransmit
4. Lower CRC quality at greater payload lengths = corrupt packets = retransmit
5. End-to-end path MTU discovery, both ways

Answer (score 0):

Your "server" should have one interface for iSCSI (this interface is the disk bus!), and one interface for clients to access the server on. The iSCSI interface should be MTU9000, the client access interface should be have a default MTU. Also, your switch needs to be configured to support both jumbo frames and flow control, or performance will suck.

Comment: It is confusing. You said one interface for iscsi, which is a disk bus, and this interface should be MTU9000. Two questions: 1) If I understand correctly, the iscsi interface should connect to the NIC. Why it is a disk card? 2) How to set MTU9000 to a disk card?

Comment: iSCSI is block level storage over TCP/IP. The users do not talk to the iSCSI storage device the server does, they talk to your server, which in turn talks to the device. Would you run really long SATA cables from your server to every desktop? NO.

Comment: But the server has one NIC. It need to use this NIC to talk to file server and client. I can only set one MTU value for this NIC

Comment: Then I suggest you add another one if this is meant to be a permanent solution and if you want ideal performance.

Comment: This isn't to say jumbo frames may not help your clients as well, but right now your disk bus is competing for bandwidth with the client communication. You may end up using jumbo frames on both NICs, but you definitely need two.

Comment: Did you mean that I need to install two NIC on the server. One for file server, one for clients?

Comment: Are the disks used to provide this storage directly connected to the server or are they external?

Comment: The disks reside on file server. The server connect to file server via 10GB network.

Comment: You're losing me here, do you or do you not have an iSCSI storage system?

Comment: How do you define a iSCSI storage system? I have a machine that hosts as file system, it contains disks. I have another machine as "server" that mount the disk in the file system as iSCSI storage system.

Comment: Okay, so you basically have a NAS that supports iSCSI, and a server that is fronting that storage to clients. In that case my suggestions hold, your "server" should have two NICs, one for communicating to what you call the "file server" and another to server data to clients. Ideally the iSCSI communication should be over another VLAN or if that's not possible, a crossover cable. You really need to tell us more about your environment.

Comment: If you're not ready to spend money on networking hardware, don't use iSCSI. Have your NAS serve clients directly, preferably NIC-teamed to your switch if it has multiple NICs. You do not front iSCSI from a cheap server with a single NIC. Synology boxes can sync with Active Directory and join domains.

Also, the iSCSI device should have >1 network port. With a fronting server, you would connect all of them machine-to-machine (crossover cable if no auto-crossover, VLAN if $$$$ switches) and team on both ends. Without you'd hook them all to the switch, team on both ends if possible, NAS-end if no

Comment: 1 gigabit is only 125MB/s, and your RAID is probably much faster. So if anyone downloads a large file over local network the NAS will choke on network traffic. You want minimum four gigabit ports on a storage server.